# Error Installing CakePHP 3.0 using composer

Tags: php, git, cakephp, composer-php

I tried to install cakephp 3.0 running:

```
composer create-project -s dev cakephp/app cakedev
```

and also git cloning [cakephp/app](https://github.com/cakephp/app) and then running composer update but I keep getting the same error:

```
Installing cakephp/cakephp (3.0.x-dev 0a2ff83)
    Cloning 0a2ff83156e5725b7e9339fb655e280ee70ce5aa
Executing command (CWD): git clone --no-checkout 'git://github.com/cakephp/cakephp.git' '/home/vagrant/www/cakedev/vendor/cakephp/cakephp' && cd '/home/vagrant/www/cakedev/vendor/cakephp/cakephp' && git remote add composer 'git://github.com/cakephp/cakephp.git' && git fetch composer
Failed: [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException] The process "git clone --no-checkout 'git://github.com/cakephp/cakephp.git' '/home/vagrant/www/cakedev/vendor/cakephp/cakephp' && cd '/home/vagrant/www/cakedev/vendor/cakephp/cakephp' && git remote add composer 'git://github.com/cakephp/cakephp.git' && git fetch composer" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.
Failed to download cakephp/cakephp from source: The process "git clone --no-checkout 'git://github.com/cakephp/cakephp.git' '/home/vagrant/www/cakedev/vendor/cakephp/cakephp' && cd '/home/vagrant/www/cakedev/vendor/cakephp/cakephp' && git remote add composer 'git://github.com/cakephp/cakephp.git' && git fetch composer" exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds.
Now trying to download from dist
  - Installing cakephp/cakephp (3.0.x-dev 0a2ff83)

Failed: [RuntimeException] Could not delete /home/vagrant/www/cakedev/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_9VVOjS:

Reading ./composer.json
Loading config file ./composer.json



  [RuntimeException]

  Could not delete /home/vagrant/www/cakedev/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_9VVOjS:
```

[image]

I tried to run the commands using sudo and also get error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove composer cache in ~/.composer/cache/* and try to increase composer timeout with this methods

Try with --prefer-dist option if not works try to increase composer timeout (default il 300)

```
export COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=600
php composer.phar install --prefer-dist
```

Answer (score 0):

```
composer clearcache
composer clear-cache
```

Just for clarification The above lines are the built in ways to clear composer cache. Both commands are the same.